# BeautifulSoup Python fetch syntax

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to gather some data from a wikipedia page and I can't seem to narrow down my fetch to the `ui` and `li` items within the div. Here's what I have so far:

```
soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': "mw-parser-output"})
```

I'm reading through the documentation and I cant seem to find where or how I can drill down to the `ul` or `li` within `div class = mw-parser-output`.

This is the first time I've used BeautifulSoup, so please excuse my ignorance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
items=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': "mw-parser-output"})
for item in items:
    print(item.find_all('li'))
```

^__^

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup supports [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with the `.select(selector)` syntax. You could use something like `soup.select('div.mw-parser-output ul li')`

Answer (score 0):

I got what I was looking for by simply using `items = soup.findAll('li')`. If there is a better way, please let me know.